# Find all integer polynomials $f(p)$ that divide $2^p–2$ for every prime $p>2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Find all polynomials $f(p)$ with integer coefficients that divide $2^p–2$ for every prime $p>2$

From Fermat's little theorem we can find $2p, p, -2p, -p$ (and per comments, some constant polynomials). But are there others, or can we prove higher degrees won't work?

Comment: There are also constant polynomials $1$ and $2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Also, similarly, there's the constant polynomials $-1$ and $-2$. In addition, note $3$ and $-3$ also always divides $2^p - 2$ for all odd $p$ (not just primes), but you can't use $3p$ or $-3p$ since it doesn't work for $p = 3$. Thus, there's also the constant polynomials $6$ and $-6$.

Comment: What does the fundamental theorem of algebra say about the factors of a polynomial of degree p-1? What happens if some of the factors have complex roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(p-1)$ is even, let $p-1=2k$, we can write:

$2^p-2=2(2^{p-1}-1)=2(2^k-1)(2^k+1)=2(2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1)(2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1)$

If $k=\frac{p-1}2=2m+1$ is odd we have:

$m=\frac{p-3}2$

Then:

$2^k-1=(2-1)(2^{2m}+2^{2m-1}+2^{2m-2}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot)=(2^{p-3}+2^{p-4}+2^{p-5}\cdot \cdot \cdot)$

Also:

$2^k+1=(2+1)(2^{2m}-2^{2m-1}+2^{2m-2}-2^{2m-3} \cdot\cdot\cdot)=3(2^{p-3}-2^{p-4}+2^{p-5}-2^{p-7}\cdot \cdot \cdot)$

Hence the factors of $2^p-2$ can at most be  ±2,  ±p,3,$A=(2^{p-3}+2^{p-4}+2^{p-5}\cdot \cdot \cdot)$ and $B=(2^{p-3}-2^{p-4}+2^{p-5}-2^{p-7}\cdot \cdot \cdot)$.
Now we construct an equation it's roots are these factors:

$[x-(2^n-2)](x±2)(x±p)(x-3)(x-A)(x-B)=0$

We can rewrite this equation as:

$f(x,p)=(±2)(3)(±p)(2^n-2)\cdot A\cdot B$

RHS of this equation divides $2^p-2$, therefore polynomial $f(x, p)$, on LHS divides it.